# New iPhone 6 - hints in Notifications

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been receiving new iphone 6 hints in my Notifications but when I go to try one out and go back to read it again it is gone.

How do I retrieve them and where do they do they come from?

Answer (score 1):

They are from a new app called Tips, added with iOS 8.

It will post occasional tips & tricks on your lock screen, but you can launch the app itself & browse through them any time you like.

Comment: Thanks but the App is not in the App store?

Comment: no, it's a core app, like Stocks or Weather - you can't delete it & it's not in the store.